# Best practices to test Asp.net MVC applications

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, testing

Whats the best practice to test an Asp.net MVC application?

Answer (score 5):

Choose your testing framework - I recommend [xUnit.net](http://www.codeplex.com/).

Decouple your classes using interfaces and use constructor injection in your controllers to satisfy dependencies. In your tests, pass mocks to your controllers using a mocking framework - I recommend [MoQ](http://code.google.com/p/moq/).

When running the web site rather than tests, either have default constructors on your controllers that call the other constructors and pass your real implementations of your interfaces; or use a Dependency Injection (DI) container to do it automatically - I recommend [StructureMap](http://structuremap.sourceforge.net/Default.htm).

Hope that helps.